# Why am i getting 401 error while making connection to mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: javascript, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to make connection with mail chimp API 3.0 using http request. But the request is blocked by CORS and i am getting 401 error from mail chimp i.e I am not passing API key. But I am passing the key. Could anyone explain how to get around this issue.

Also I cannot use any plugin or libraries for this project. It has to be Vanilla JavaScript.

Thank you

```
get : function(url,callback) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
    "email_address": "test2@test.ca",
    "status": "subscribed"
    });


    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
            callback(response);
        }
    }; 

    request.open('get',url,true);

    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('anystring' + ':' + myapikey));
    request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    request.send(data);
}
```

for reference this is sample code from mailchimp.

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/' \
--user 'anystring:<your_apikey>'
```

Error : 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listid/members' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and clicking on the link gives me

{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"API Key Missing","status":401,"detail":"Your request did not include an API key.","instance":"c8c5e111-6969-41a1-9e68-f545959ba6c5"}

[Console.log(request);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtwCM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see four things that could be causing issues here:

1. Try using the 'get' HTTP method for the call, like in the sample code from mailchimp.
2. You need to base64 encode your username and password for the `Authentication` header.
3. There is a space missing between "Basic" and the actual authentication token.
4. You are not using the [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) method properly, when setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. The value should be its own parameter.

Try this:

```
    request.open('get',url,true);

    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('anystring' + ':' + myapikey));
    request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    request.send(data);
```

Comment: Hey Andreas, I made the changes but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm, can you `console.log(request)` before the send, and add it to the question? Just replace the Authorization header value with xxxx's before you share it (otherwise you will be sharing your API key).

Comment: I am not getting any authorization header value, I have attached image for reference